# HTMLDecode string array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

how can i decode `string[]` using `LINQ`?

eg. I'm getting `string` as `Institute&amp;apos;s` from my `string[]` instead of `Institute's`

i tried,

`values.ForEach(item => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item));`

where `values` is my `string[]`..

still I'm not able to get the desired result.

**EDIT:**

as shown above my original string is `Institution's` and i'm getting it as encoded

`Institute&apos;s` ----> first level encoding

`Institute&amp;apos;s` ---->second level encoding

after applying following solutions, i'm able to get result decoded first level encoding above as

`Institute&apos;s`

but not able to get the actual string `Institute's`

Comment: Try Select instead of foreach

Comment: @HenrikJepsen: tried `Select` instead of `ForEach` still same result

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing any changes is that `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` does not assign a value to the parameter you pass it, instead, it returns the html decoded value.

```
    String encodedString = "&amp;";

    //this does nothing
    WebUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedString);

    //this assigns the decoded value to a new string
    String decodedString = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedString);
```

This is also why (as Henrik mentioned) you should use `Select` in your linq query.

You would use it like this:

```
values = values.Select(item => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item));
```

Comment: Your 2nd version (`values.ForEach`) wont work as you just assign the decoded value to the variable `item` but never set it in the array. You need a for loop to do that.

Comment: woops, it gets even worse. you can't do `ForEach` on an array, you need a `List<T>` for that.

Comment: @TimothyGroote: `values = values.Select(item => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item));` doesnt worked

Comment: @TimothyGroote You can do ForEach on array, but the syntax is a little different. `Array.ForEach(values, item => ...)`

Comment: @TimothyGroote: `values = values.Select(item => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item));` doesnt worked..with this i'm able to get the result as `Institute&apos;s`. it decoded only the `&amp;` and not `apos;`.

Comment: This is because the data you're inputting is not corectly formatted. `apos;`, when run through `HtmlDecode` returns `apos;`.
`&apos;` however would return `'`.
I'm suspecting the value is html encoded *twice*.
I'm not sure where your data comes from, but this sounds like a problem you should try to fix elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This code snipped worked for me:

```
string[] values = new string[] {
    "Institute&amp;apos;s",
    "Institute&amp;apos;s",
    "Institute&amp;apos;s",
    "Institute&amp;apos;s",
    "Institute&amp;apos;s"};

List<string> decoded = new List<string>();
Regex encDet = new Regex(@"\&.+;", RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

values.ToList().ForEach(item => {
string decodedItem = item;
while(encDet.IsMatch(decodedItem)){
        decodedItem = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(decodedItem);
}
decoded.Add(decodedItem);
});
values = decoded.ToArray();
```

**EDIT:**

If you need just "pure" LINQ that would just decode double-encoded strings, here is another one-line snippet:

```
values = values.Select(item => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item))).ToArray();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var decodedValues = HtmlDoubleDecode(values);
```

where HtmlDoubleDecode is:

```
public string[] HtmlDoubleDecode(string[] values)
{
    return values
        .Select (v => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(v)))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This would work (in this particular case), but it'd rather be fighting symptoms of a deeper problem, rather than solving the root of the problem.